# move git repository and files from Ubuntu to OS-X

Tags: macos, git, ubuntu

I've been using Git on my Linux (Ubuntu) machine to track changes to C++ code. 
Now, i'm working on Mac (OS-X 10.8), so i though i will just copy the whole folder of sources together with .git from Linux to Mac. 
However, that does not lead to anything good. Git lists me huge number of modified files, i guess all of them. 
I'm not sure, but i guess that might have something to do with the line endings in Linux and OS-X. So, what is the correct sequence of actions i should do in such situation to have a smooth transfer from one OS to another?

Thanks in advance,
Denis.

**EDIT**
solved the issue by setting 
filemode=false in .git/config

is it the proper solution? I don't quite understand what caused a problem?

**EDIT2**
forgot to mention, the original repository is cloned from "git://..."

**EDIT3** 
apparently, the problem was that i used a USB flash drive to carry things from one os to another, and did not thought that it could make my life harder :) coppied everything again from scratch without USB and the problem is gone.

Comment: Don't you want to share the git repo between the machines?

Comment: @trojanfoe, not really, i just move from one OS to another.

Comment: Use `git diff` and see what has changed.

Comment: @trojanfoe, that's what i have from git diff (one of many, all the same): 'diff --git a/LICENSE b/LICENSE old mode 100644 new mode 100755' no idea what it means...

Comment: That just means the file permissions have changed and they shouldn't have.  A better way of moving the repo would be to simply clone it (via ssh or samba or something) and then edit the .git/config to remove the remote.

Comment: Your file permissions for some reason has changed.  Just reclone.

Comment: Did you use a USB key to transfer the files?  I find this sort of thing happens when you have a FAT file system in the middle.  Another way to fix the state would be to simply run `git checkout .`.  That would restore the state of all files to `HEAD`.

Comment: @jszakmeister bingo! that was exactly the problem! just did it again without FAT USB and everything is fine. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have ssh access to your account on the Ubuntu machine, I suggest cloning over `ssh`:

```
$ git clone ssh://user@ubuntu-machine/path/to/git/repo
```

By using the actual `git clone` operation on your Mac OS X machine you shouldn't run into any problems.

For reference, the **GIT URLS** section of the [git-clone man page](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-clone.html) has all the URL format of all possible git transports.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, i'll try to set up an ssh now and see if i get any different results...